# At $x_0 \in \partial \Omega$, $\text{Hess}u(x_0) = \Delta u(x_0) (\nu \otimes \nu)$, $\nu$ outer unit normal

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle, hessian-matrix, elliptic-equations

Let $x_0 \in \partial \Omega$ and $\nu(x_{0})$ is the exterior unit normal at $x_0$, with $\nu_1(x_0) > 0$, where $u \in C^{2}(\overline{\Omega_{\epsilon}})$ and $\Omega_{\epsilon}=\Omega \cap \{|x-x_0|<\epsilon\}$, $u>0$ in $\Omega$ and $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega \cap \{|x-x_0|<\epsilon\}$. We know that $u_{x_1}(x_0) = 0$. Why does the following hold?

$$
\Delta u = - f(0) > 0 \implies u_{x_{i},x_{j}}=-f(0)\nu_{i}\nu_{j} \quad \text{ at } x_0
$$

Moreover, in their paper, Gidas, Ni and Nirenberg claim, right before what inspires the question, that $\nabla u(x_0) = 0$. It's a mistake, isn't it? Up to my understanding, we only know that $u_1(x_0) = 0$.

This expression appears specifically in the last part of the demonstration of Lemma 2.1 of this article https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103905359 of Gidas-Ni-Nirenberg's and I think that it is related to the second directional derivative and Hessian matrix.

Comment: Can you please provide the context (what is $v$, for example)?

Comment: @cmk They refer to v_i as component i of the external normal vector

Answer (score 1):

It’s not a mistake. Since $u=0$ on the boundary, the tangential derivative of $u$ is zero on the boundary. If $t_1$, $\ldots$, $t_{n-1}$ are the tangent vectors, you can write $$e_1=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}c_it_i+c_n\nu$$
Taking the inner product with $\nu$ you get that $c_n=\nu_1>0$. Hence $0=u_1=\nabla u\cdot e_1=c_nu_\nu$ at $x_0$ and so also the normal derivative is zero. Hence the gradient is zero.
For the Laplacian you have to do something similar. All the second derivatives in the tangential directions will be zero.

Comment: Many thanks! I will post another answer with the details of the second part, just to serve as a reference for others who may be in trouble with this, but I'm awarding you the bounty, of course. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The following argument is due to Adam Rudnik and Vitor Borges, making use of the hint by Gio67

Since the Laplace operator is invariant by rotations and translations, and since every tangential derivative is $0$ we can write it with respect to the basis $\{t_1, \ldots, t_{N - 1}, \nu\}$ as
$$
\Delta u(x_0) = u_{\nu \nu}.
$$
But
$$
u_{ij} = [u_{ij}](e_i, e_j) = [u_{ij}] (\nu_i \nu, \nu_j \nu) = \nu_i \nu_j [u_{ij}](\nu, \nu) = \nu_i \nu_j u_{\nu \nu} = \nu_i \nu_j \Delta u(x_0),
$$